# Calling max method on an enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumeration

In this code:

```
people = [ p1, p2, p3 ]
people.map { |p| p.age }.max
```

- Isn't this code creating an array and then calling `max` on it?
- Isn't this the waste of memory because of a redundant array
  created by `map` method?
- Couldn't we just call `max` on any enumerators and compute
  the maximum on the fly?

Comment: In future, consider waiting a couple of hours before selecting an answer. You don't want to discourage other answers. There's no rush.

Comment: Waste of memory isn't valid unless it's going to create an out-of-memory condition since garbage collection will clean it up. A more usable question to me is, which is the fastest way to calculate the `max` value if you have a huge array. Benchmarks hold the key to that question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry, I didn't know this law. I will consider it the next time.

Comment: It's not a law. Lots of people here believe quick-draw selections are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `map` creates a temp array. Yes, you can use `max` directly on an enumerable using its block form

```
the_eldest_one = people.max { |p1, p2| p1.age <=> p2.age }
# or
the_eldest_one = people.max_by(&:age)
```

Comment: But then you have to recalculate `age` on the max element. It is a trade off.

Comment: what do you mean, recalculate `age`? I assume this is a plain field access, not a calculated field. And, as such, it is quite cheap.

Comment: If you don't like the term "recalculate", you can substitute with "re-call". Whether it is cheap depends on what OP has. It all depends on that. Furthermore, using the Schwarzian-style would be better.

Comment: I would instead use `max_by`.  `people.max_by(&:age)`.  That only calls the method once per item instead of twice per comparison.  Not sure if it does anything different as far as turning an iterator into an array, though.

Comment: Sergio, you don't need to use `<=>`, as [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) with a block returns the object whose computed block value is largest (using `<=>`, of course), so `people.max { |p| p.age }` is enough. Either way, you still need to tack on `.age` to get the age, of course.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: you confused `max` with `max_by`. `max` yields two elements to the block, so you have to do the spaceship. http://pastie.org/10441035

Comment: You're right (but you know that). Beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Sergio's answer is great, but as an alternative way:

Yes, it creates a new array. Yes, it is a waste. The way to avoid both creating an intermediate array and also recalculating the value is to do it manually. Assuming max is at least `0` (which you can change):

```
people.inject(0){|max, e| _max = e.age; _max > max ? _max : max}
```

Comment: needs to be `person.age`, not just `person`.